# Parse a formula which contains variables from HashMap

Tags: java, parsing, hashmap

I have created the following hashmap:

```
HashMap<String, String> toleranceValues = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

which contains variable names and their respective values, eg:

```
 "ANGLE"="3.0"
```

Given this hashmap, I need to use the variables in it to parse a math formula contained in a regular String, eg:

```
 String formula = " ANGLE*PI/2";
```

The problem does not involve math parsing since I have already found the solution using JEval.. I just need a way to get the value of my variable stored in the map and which appears in the formula.

Comment: You can make a linear scan through the string `formula` and retrieving the textual parts. These textual parts would be the name of your variables, which you can then lookup in the HashMap.

Comment: From the JEval homepage (http://jeval.sourceforge.net/) under the list of features - 'Supports variables and 'Allows for custom variable resolver' - I'd look at how that feature works, in particular - http://jeval.sourceforge.net/docs/api/net/sourceforge/jeval/Evaluator.html#setVariables(java.util.Map)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [unit tests for JEval](http://jeval.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jeval/jeval/test/net/sourceforge/jeval/JEvalTests.java?view=markup) you define variables in a formula with the format `#{[variable name]}`.  This information is also in the JavaDocs for [Evaluator](http://jeval.sourceforge.net/docs/api/net/sourceforge/jeval/Evaluator.html).

Given this requirement for variable names, for the formula above to work, the code would look like this:

```
  Map variables = new HashMap();
  variables.put("ANGLE", "3.0");
  variables.put("PI", "3.14");

  Evaluator evaluator = new Evaluator();
  evaluator.setVariables(variables);

  String result = evaluator.evaluate("#{ANGLE} * #{PI} / 2"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The formula can be treated as a [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.org/) template which will be populated with the values from the map.

Comment: It's not immediately obvious but the OP states they are using JEval.